# MKPinAnnotationView downloaded image (@3x) not working for 6+

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, mkannotation, mkpinannotationview

I am using map on my application, For pin drop, I want to set user's image instead of default pin.

I am downloading users image and setting it as per code I paste below.

For different scale of devices I am using image name as per device scale like eg.,

**1 For non retina device - pin.png    (size 30 x 30)**

**2 For retina devices    - pin@2x.png (size 60 x 60)**

**3 For 6+ device         - pin@3x.png (size 90 x 90)**

Here for 1 and 2 working fine and image loads perfect But for 6+ (3x scale) it's not working

**What's issue is:**

For 6+ I am downloading pin@3x image, But on map it's size is 90 x 90 that should be 30 x 30. As it simply works for images when we use from application bundle.

For pin@2x.png it works fine and shows 2x image in size 30 x 30.

I also tried below solution by setting scale of image but not works

[MKPinAnnotationView: Are there more than three colors available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185611/)

I have tried my best to explain actual issue, Can any one guide please if I am missing any thing or if it's require to set anything?

**Code**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
{
    return nil;
}

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[KPAnnotation class]])
{
    //Custom annotation class for pin drop
    KPAnnotation *a = (KPAnnotation *)annotation;

    annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"pin"];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:[a.annotations anyObject]
                                                         reuseIdentifier:@"pin"];
    }

    //Image View to add subview in MKPinAnnotationView
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"];
    imageView.image=image;

    //Test URL - see image name here
    NSString *readAWSURL=@"<domainname.com>/pin@3x.png";

    //Downloading image here to load with async way (SDWebImage)
    [imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:readAWSURL] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"]];

    annotationView.image=imageView.image;
    [annotationView addSubview:imageView];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
}

return annotationView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **MKAnnotationView** in place of **MKPinAnnotationView**

```
- (MKAnnotationView ) mapView: (MKMapView ) mapViewIn viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>) annotation
{

static NSString *annotationViewReuseIdentifier = @"annotationViewReuseIdentifier";

MKAnnotationView annotationView = (MKAnnotationView )[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifier];

if (annotationView == nil)
{
    annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifier];
}

if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]]) {
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"orange.png"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
}
else{
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
    annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
}

annotationView.annotation = annotation;
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: well, I had issue was with download image and show on map. There was no issue with show image from bundle. To show from bundle it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

My answer working nowadays for me. It based on `pod 'SDWebImage'`,`pod 'UIImage-Resize'`  and bearded answer from @mokriya http://mokriya.tumblr.com/post/15342072745/dynamic-annotations-mkannotationview-for-ios
Just add category MKAnnotationView(WebCache):

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MKAnnotationView(WebCache)

- (void)setImageWithUrl:(NSURL *)url;

@end
```

and implementation (not a perfect but worked one):

```
#import "MKAnnotationView+WebCache.h"
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
#import "UIImage+Resize.h"

#define kIconSize CGSizeMake(50, 50)

@implementation MKAnnotationView(WebCache)

- (void)setImageWithUrl:(NSURL *)url {
    [[[UIImageView alloc] init] sd_setImageWithURL:url completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
        self.image = [image resizedImageToSize:kIconSize];
    }];
}

@end
```

and using:

```
#pragma mark - MKMapViewDelegate

- (nullable MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    static NSString *annotationViewReuseIdentifier = @"annotationViewReuseIdentifier";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifier];

    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:annotationViewReuseIdentifier];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }

    annotationView.annotation = <YOUR ANNOTATION>;
    [annotationView setImageWithUrl:<HERE IS THE URL>];

    return annotationView;
}
```